# Elasticsearch 5 connector in Apache Flink 1.3

Tags: maven, elasticsearch, apache-flink

By reading the documentation I understood that with Apache Flink 1.3 I should be able to use Elasticsearch 5.x.

However, in my pom.xml :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-elasticsearch5_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I got this :

> Dependency
>   "org.apache.flink:flink-connector-elasticsearch5_2.10:1.3.0" not found

Any idea why this dependency is unfound ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in the 1.3.0 release and is being fixed for 1.3.1 (which is due very soon). See [the mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flink-dev/201706.mbox/%3CetPan.593124a1.6bb6e426.1625d%40apache.org%3E) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-connector-elasticsearch5_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```